# indexOf in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an array like this `emp=["111","56"]`.
My code is:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter" class="form-control" name="Emp" ng-model="myModel.Emp" ng-required="currentStep ==2"/>

 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" class="form-control" name="EmpS" ng-model="myModel.EmpS" ng-required="currentStep == 2"/>

<span ng-if="(emp.indexOf('{{myModel.Emp}}') > -1 ) ? (myModel.EmpS=''):(myModel.EmpS=emp.indexOf('{{myModel.Emp}}'))" ></span>
```

Is it right? It always goes to the false condition. Please help me.

Comment: Always do your `conditional`/`logical` work in `controller`. Keep things simple..

Comment: What you want to check in the condition. Unable to make out from the syntax provided..

Comment: Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/n5opy8as/

Comment: i get it from the below comment. thanks for ur time.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work if u use like this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<div ng-init='emp=["111","56"]'>


 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" class="form-control" name="Emp" ng-model="Emp" ng-required="currentStep ==2"/>

 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" class="form-control" name="EmpS" ng-model="EmpS" ng-required="currentStep == 2"/>
<span ng-if="(emp.indexOf(Emp) == -1 ) ? (EmpS=''):(EmpS=emp.indexOf(Emp))" ></span>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<div ng-init='emp=["111","56"]'>
```